# Invisible text in footer only upon opening in new Firefox browser session

Tags: css, firefox

I have an odd issue with a website that I maintain: On the homepage, the text in the footer menu is 'invisible' (it's there, but the text is the same color as the background) *only* when I open it in a *new* browser session in Firefox.

If I navigate to another page on the site, the text is visible. If I navigate *back* to the home page, or open the homepage again in a new tab, the text is visible. If I open the page in Safari or Chrome, the text is always visible. It's ONLY an issue in Firefox, and ONLY when I open the homepage in a new browser session.

I'm not sure where to begin to debug this problem -- I checked out the CSS for the footer and it looks fine (i.e., the text color is correct).

The site is here: http://uucj.org

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Comment: You don't need a new session, hard refresh is enough. Not sure if the cause could be font -> `#mp-brick-174 * {
    font-family: 'Oxygen:Light,300';
}`. When I disable it in dev tools, the text appears.

Comment: You are required to post your markup or code here, not your web site which will change or disappear in the future rendering your question and the answers useless for anyone else. [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed when I disabled this style (#mp-brick-174 *) in your CSS for the font family it appeared and was working.

Disabled Style: #mp-brick-174 *

Instead of doing this:

```
font-family:'Oxygen:Light,300';
```

Try this:

```
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
```